# How I can block user to go back to the previous page in flutter

Tags: flutter

I uses to navigate to a new screen :

```
 Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CardsListView(pageId)))
```

the problem is the user can go back to the previous page and I don't want to allow him to be able to do that. Anyone know how I can do that?

Comment: You can do that with a custom navigator. The reason you need it is authorization/login page?

Comment: Use [`Navigator.pushReplacement`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NavigatorState/pushReplacement.html) or [`pushAndRemoveUntil`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NavigatorState/pushAndRemoveUntil.html)

Comment: thank's that's help me

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the route.

```
      Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ResultsPage()),
          (route) => route.isFirst);
```

Or

```
void _logout() {
   Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, "/newRouteName", (r) => false);
}
```

There are other methods which may be useful:

- https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Navigator/replace.html
- https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushReplacement.html
- https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Navigator/popAndPushNamed.html